# I am using JQuery DataTable Column Filter plugin..select filter not gets populated?

Tags: jquery

I am using  JQuery DataTable Column Filter plugin...It works fine but the only thing is the select dropdown not gets populated...I am using server side fetching..how to do that i.e auto populated?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [{
            type: "select",
            values: ['Gecko', 'Trident', 'KHTML', 'Misc', 'Presto', 'Webkit', 'Tasman']
        }, {
            type: "text"
        },
        null, {
            type: "number"
        }, {
            type: "select"
        }]
    });
});
```

IF I specify { type: "select"} with out values its not working..But the document says it will auto populated...

Answer (score 0):

According issue 34: auto-build does not work when data is processed in the server (bServerSide = true)

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/issues/detail?id=34